# rails - URL doesn't match with the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have something strange in my rails app, I try to redirect the user to a specific page if a form is wrong formatted. It works but the URL does not match to the view.

I use files generated by `rails g scaffold User`. I added specific condition in model file to check user input to see if the form is well formatted or not and if not, it redirect him to the connection view.

**I redirect him between 2 different controllers**

So i turned this (app/controller/users_controller.rb):

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

into this:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :template => 'pages/connection' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I tried and i'm well redirected to *pages/connection.rb* but the url in my browser is : `http://url:8080/users` and not `http://url:8080/connection`. So if i refresh, it leave *pages/connection.rb* to *users/*.

Also, error messages from *model/user.rb* aren't displayed.

what's wrong in my code ?

Comment: `Also, error messages from model/user.rb aren't displayed.` - have you tried to list them in your view?

Comment: indeed i copy paste some content from files created by scaffold and i forget to copy user.errors.full_messages

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering the template pages/connection, you are not redirecting the user to the other controller.

```
format.html { render :template => 'pages/connection' }
```

Render and redirect are not the same

Comment: Yes i know, i used the wrong vocabulary. I don't want to use redirect_to because i need to catch post request that's why i need render

Comment: @Tellimi Sorry - I am not sure what your question is in that case. What are you trying to accomplish? Using render will not update the URL for the user - this is correct behaviour. That would only be accomplished by a redirect.

Comment: I understand better how it works and i'm not in the same point in my project so now. I'll be more precise. I wish to send my user on the view 'connection'. I must send error message from model so i must use render and if i use render the URL is /users. If i use redirect_to, messages are not displayed. Is it possible to send user to the view connection with the url /connection but still with my error messages?